# Trace identity deduction - linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

In a lemma building up to the proof of Cartan's criterion for solubility they deduce something that I don't follow. This is likely due to some deficit in my knowledge of linear algebra.

I'll outline the general argument in case the context matters:

$\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues for a linear transformation. $E$ is the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space spanned by them. Trying to show that every $f$ in the dual of $E$ is zero. $y$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $f(\lambda_1),\ldots,f(\lambda_n)$. Then there are some arguments which conclude with $0=\sum f(\lambda_i)^2$.

They then say that this implies $f(\lambda_i)=0$. I can't see why this is true, can someone point it out?

Thanks.

Comment: Ah.  Is this Humphreys?  I remember loving this proof

Comment: I don't have the book at hand, but this is strange at first sight. Every $f$ in the dual being zero implies that all those eigenvalues are zero; is that what is being proved here? In any case the dual would be $L_\Bbb Q(E,\Bbb Q)$, so its elements take rational values, and their squares are positive.

Comment: I've uploaded the proof from the book here: http://i.imgur.com/egjmNM1.png

Comment: That version explains some details better, it's from Humphreys? I'm learning from a set of lecture notes at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(\lambda_i)^2 \geq 0$ and so $$\sum f(\lambda_i)^2 = 0 \iff f(\lambda_i) = 0$$

Comment: Man that's embarrassing that I missed that, thanks for answering.

Comment: No probs, these things happen to everyone.  I still favourited this question because I want to remind myself to look through that proof again so the question didn't go to waste for at least one person :)